# WPF property changed but not using binded collection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, reference

I have a tree in WPF and a Hierarhical data structure like this:

```
  <TreeView x:Name="MainTreeview"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400"  VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="500" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding NodeVmList}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
.....
```

So, if I update a `NodeViewModel` from the 1st level in the tree, the changes will be reflected in the UI, for example `IsEpanded` property. But if I update a node but not using Children Property and using direct reference to the `NodeViewModel` object, the changes are not reflected on th UI.

Comment: how do you change it /

Comment: I have an other collection wich store the references to this objects.

Comment: Every NodeViewModel property call in the setter NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @florinflo have you tried ..{Binding Path=Children, ...? Sometimes the bindings can be picky about the Path keyword being in there.

Answer (score 0):

The [roblem was that I had the same information in the objects, but the objects was different.